# how to join the domain the using winbind and samba with password in automation

Tags: rhel, samba, domain, automake, winbind

I have installed samba and winbind in rhel8.

I was trying to automate the domain join process as well. But when try it manually it is working as expected when we enter the password manually for "**service-user-account**" for domain join.

But I don't see any command to automate with the password. I have tried with one of the below command, but it is giving an error.

**Command:**
net ads join -U $ad_user%$password

but I am getting below error. I have put the *service account user and password in variable*.

**error:**
Failed to join domain: failed to lookup DC info for domain 'example.com' over rpc: The attempted logon is invalid. This is either due to a bad username or authentication information.

**Kindly help me to automate this step**. Appreciate your kind support!.

Thanks
Uma

Comment: did you try ` export USER="${aduser}%${password}"`?

Comment: @crpb thanks for helping me. I have tried with this as well.
net ads join -U $(ad_user)%$(password)

one more thing that I noticed one of the team member has done in ansible. it's working. any suggestion in shell script?

-  name: domainjoin command

    
command: net ads join -U {{admin}}%{{}password}}

Comment: I guess this is a typo: "$(ad_user)%$(password)"? {} not () or alt. `net ads join -U "$ad_user"%"%$password"`. And you followed the [Samba-Doc](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member)?

Comment: Thanks for helping me. below command worked for me.
net ads join -U $ad_user%$domainpass

Comment: We can close this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution with below command:

```
net ads join -U $ad_user%$domainpass
```

Comment: What's the difference? It looks like you're just using a different variable name